# elementary OS is too slow (Ubuntu 15.04 as well)

Tags: drivers, 15.04, elementary

I installed elementary OS Freya awhile ago and it was so slow, so I went back to Ubuntu. Now I decided I will give it another shot, and it's still the same.

Sometimes the panel takes 2 to 3 min to change to black or to normal. It takes too long to boot. It lags even worse when I'm installing a software, some times I can't even click anything. I've installed the additional drivers.

I really love the work they done, and I'm fascinated by the OS design and the DE. So I really want this to work.

```
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-3612QM CPU @ 2.10GHz × 8
Memory   : 8 GB
Graphics : Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
```

To make this more relevant, I had the same problem with Ubuntu 15.04, I had to install 14.04 to have Ubuntu working as fast as it should be.

Comment: I doubt there's really much to be done.